# Getting initialization error "NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/io/URLOutputStream" after integrating cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter

Tags: cucumber

**Cucumber V. 4.2.3 | Selenium V.3.8.1 | JUnit V.4.12 | Extent Report V. 3.1.1**

**I am facing error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/io/URLOutputStream" while integrating "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" under plugin in RunCuke** Java file

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                     tags = { "@guest_plp" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                              "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports",
                              "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class FunctionalRunCuke {
}
```

[Error Screen Shot from Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iheHp.png)

**Trying to add extent cucumber adapter in POM.xml as given below -**

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**If I remove "extentreports-cucumber4-adapter" then i do not get compile time error mentioned below -**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/io/URLOutputStream
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.findSingleArgConstructor(PluginFactory.java:141)
        at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:82)
        at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:73)
        at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:65)
        at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:37)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runtime.io.URLOutputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 27 more
```

**I have added below dependency in POM.xml**

```
<!-- ********************************()() CUCUMBER & SELENIUM DEPENDENCIES ()()******************************** --> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Have someone faced this issue before. Does Cucumber V 4.2.3 Support extentreports-cucumber4-adapter plugin. If so then any guess, what is wrong here which is causing this error.

Comment: Try with 4.2.0... This was removed in 4.2.1 https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v4.2.0/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/io

Comment: Looks like `extentreports-cucumber4-adapter` is using internal cucumber API's. You should file a ticket with them.

Comment: What is the reason behind using Extent 3.x with the adapter? The adapter is to be only used with Extent 4.x. You do not need to use the ExtentReports dependency, also the com.vimalselvam dependency must be removed.

Comment: Hey @Grasshopper, when I run it using cucumber v 4.0.0 or 4.2.0 then it's running successfully.

Comment: Hi @foursyth, I am new to cucumber 4.0.0 So was  having thought about  adapter that I would provide support for generating consolidated extent report. I used it. But now I am understanding we shall use adapter with extent report v4. Can you help us to understand what benefit adapter provides to extent report or cucumber or when we shall use this adapter.

Comment: @Grasshopper Is there a solution instead of downgrading?

Comment: @silver Check this [link](http://grasshopper.tech/824/) for more details. Created a custom jar with the missing class. Have tested till 4.3.1, should work for latest too...

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for that info, there is also an open defect [here](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter/issues/17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is raised because you are using ExtentReports version 3 with the cucumber  adapter, which is meant for version ExtentReports v4 only. If removing the dependency does not resolve the issue, I would suggest share your pom.xml.

Comment: Now I have only adapter dependency is POM.xml (removed com.aventstack & com.vimalselvam dependencies) and report is getting generated. As per my understanding, if we use adapter, then we do not need to pass out steps info an other stuff we had been doing without adapter like flush the extent report and a lot to add on. But is there any way if we want to add some message into report, how it can be done

Comment: That's the idea behind these adapters: to allow you to create reports with 0 configuration and setup effort.

Comment: To add additional info, use scenario.write in AfterStep.

Comment: Okay I get the whole idea now. Thank you so much @foursyth. Just because of your quick response, we are able to close this query now and I would share these ideas on other post whenever required.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. When I am using cucumber-core v4.2.2. I am getting NoClassDefFoundError cucumber.runtime.io.URLOutputStream.
On using v4.2.0 getting NoClassDefFoundError cucumber.runtime.io.RunnerOptions.

Answer (score 2):

The above issue will get resolved by adding below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already provided by @Grasshopper but in the comments section. So, I thought I will put it in the main section as some users might not go through all the comments.

This error is seen if we use cucumber-java version > v4.2.0. So, if you are using most recent version, please downgrade it to v4.2.0.

For your understanding, this is how my pom looks:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a solution without downgrading? While this works, it is a workaround.